# Extract html cell data XPath

Tags: python, xpath, html-table, extract

I have this simple html table:

```
<tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font" >
<td>OPEN</td>
<td>80002</td>
<td>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
ACCY
</span> 
<A HREF="http://bulletin.gwu.edu/search/?P=ACCY+2001" target="_blank">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
2001
</span>
</A>
</td>

<td>10</td>
<td>Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td>3.00</td>
<td> Ray, K</td>
<td><a href="http://virtualtour.gwu.edu/#MON" target="_blank" >MON</a> 113</td>
<td>MW<br>12:45PM - 02:00PM</td>
<td>08/25/14 - 12/06/14</td>
<td>

</td>
</tr>
```

I am using xpath and requests with Python. Using the xpath function how would I extract all the 'td' titles out of this table and separate them with a comma?

I want the extracted data to look like this:

```
OPEN, 80002, ACCY 2001, 10, Intro to Financial Accounting, 3.00, Ray, K, MW 12:45-02:00PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**Code:**

```
src = """<tr align="center" class="tableRow1Font" >
<td>OPEN</td>
<td>80002</td>
<td>
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
ACCY
</span> 
<A HREF="http://bulletin.gwu.edu/search/?P=ACCY+2001" target="_blank">
<span style="font-weight:bold;">
2001
</span>
</A>
</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>Intro Financial Accounting</td>
<td>3.00</td>
<td> Ray, K</td>
<td><a href="http://virtualtour.gwu.edu/#MON" target="_blank" >MON</a> 113</td>
<td>MW<br>12:45PM - 02:00PM</td>
<td>08/25/14 - 12/06/14</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>"""

from lxml import html

tree = html.fromstring(src)
tds = tree.xpath("//td/descendant-or-self::*/text()[normalize-space()]")

print ", ".join([td.strip() for td in tds])
```

**Result:**

```
OPEN, 80002, ACCY, 2001, 10, Intro Financial Accounting, 3.00, Ray, K, MON, 113, MW, 12:45PM - 02:00PM, 08/25/14 - 12/06/14
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

Note that this gets all the text from inside all `td` tags, including the ones from inside the `<a>` child node, ie. `MON`.

Cleaning the result is up to you.